# ./mvnw spring-boot:run command displays a "not found" error

Tags: maven, maven-3

thi command for running the server doesn`t work and displays: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkiTF.png)

Comment: Please try avoiding uploading picture when asking a question, Check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) to have a better idea why not post pictures, and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to start, then `Edit the system Environment Variables`

Then go to `Advanced` tab, press `Environment Variables`

Click on `New..` at `System Variables` half

add `JAVA_HOME` at variable name, and `$PATH` at `variable value`

`$PATH` is where you have `java` installed, It Should be something like this `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_291`

A simpler solution would be using CMD run as administrator

`setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_291" /M`